# moving image to bounce or rotate in a circle

Tags: c#, winforms

I found this small application that i've been playing around with for the past little while. I was wondering, if i wanted to simply rotate the image in a circle? or make the entire image just bounce up and down, how would i modify this program to do so? Everything i've tried will just stretch the image - even if i do get it to move to the left or to the right. Any ideas on what i can do? Code is below

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
          private int width = 15;
          private int height = 15;

          Image pic = Image.FromFile("402.png");
          private Button abort = new Button();
          Thread t;

          public Form1()
          {
            abort.Text = "Abort";
            abort.Location = new Point(190, 230);
            abort.Click += new EventHandler(Abort_Click);
            Controls.Add(abort);

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer| ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint| ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

            t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
            t.Start();
          }
          protected void Abort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
          {
            t.Abort();
          }

          protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )   
          {
             Graphics g = e.Graphics;
             g.DrawImage(pic, 10, 10, width, height);
             base.OnPaint(e);
          }

          public void Run() 
          {

              while (true) 
              {
                for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) 
                {
                    width += 5;

                  Invalidate();
                  Thread.Sleep(30);
                }

              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: you're gonna have to be a bit more descriptive. 
You can't just code-dump and expect someone to reason through your stuff. What exactly are you going for? What have you tried that hasn't worked? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: specific in what sense? i'm just loading an image.. and i just want to move the entire image in a circle... or just make the entire image move up and then down. Rather than what it does currently, which is zoom.

Comment: Are you looking to translate the image instantly in a circular motion, rotate it, make it move gradually in a circle as time goes, on? "Move in a circle" and "bounce" is a bit ambiguous. Also, what are you trying that is going wrong? You're trying to do some animation, right?

Comment: gradually, i want to get a keyframe effect going essentially. but to do it without using xaml. i want to be able to do this effect on any image, just as long as i load in the image.. does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but to get the fundies out of the way, WinForms is a GDI+ library and its meant more for GUI stuff, so something like animation will probably be handled better by a graphics library like [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).

Anyways, there's a million ways to achieve what you want.  In terms of moving something around in a circle, you're gonna need a little simple trig. For a bouncing motion, I would say following a sine curve would be the easiest way.

Here's some pseudo-code (not sure if this is syntax-perfect) for bouncing:

Field Definitions:

```
private double frame = 0;
```

OnPaint:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawImage(pic, 10, 10 + Math.sin(frame)*10, width, height);
frame+=.01;
base.OnPaint(e);
```

This way, every time the paint event is triggered, t will increase by .01 radians. The sin has a domain that will oscillate between -1 and 1, and you can multiply that by a factor of 10 to get that bouncing effect.

Frame represents your "keyframe". If you want to speed it up, increase the `frame+=__` to a higher value.  If you want to increase the range, change the offset `Math.sin(frame)*__`